# Conditional if loop for array multiplication - R

Tags: arrays, r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I am trying to multiply an array by a certain value. The array contains dates, and thus I would like to exclude them. I would like to use an `if` loop. I know there are other ways.

Data:

```
Date <- c("2014-12-18","2015-01-16", "2015-01-30")
W1 <- c("456", "468", "789") 
W2 <- c("456", "468", "789")
W3 <- c("456", "468", "789") 
df <- data.frame(Date, W1,W2,W3)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Current `if` loop which is not working:

```
if(names(df) != "Date"){
  df_m <- df*0.0254
}
```

It is selecting the names of the columns I want, and I think it's multipling those rather than the data itself.

Comment: If it is the first column you need `if(names(df)[1] != 'Date' {....}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coerce your `W` columns to numeric, and then it is just:

```
df_m <- data.frame(df$Date, df[,-1]*0.0254)
```

That is, with your data as:

```
Date <- c("2014-12-18","2015-01-16", "2015-01-30")
W1 <- as.numeric(c("456", "468", "789")) 
W2 <- as.numeric(c("456", "468", "789"))
W3 <- as.numeric(c("456", "468", "789")) 
df <- data.frame(Date, W1,W2,W3)
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

We get:

```
df_m <- data.frame(df$Date, df[,-1]*0.0254)    
##     df.Date      W1      W2      W3
##1 2014-12-18 11.5824 11.5824 11.5824
##2 2015-01-16 11.8872 11.8872 11.8872
##3 2015-01-30 20.0406 20.0406 20.0406
```

If you insist in using a loop then use a `for` loop (i.e., `if` is not a loop):

```
df_m <- df  
for (i in which(names(df) != "Date")) {
  df_m[, i] <- df_m[, i] * 0.0254
}
```

Again, the `W` columns should be `numeric`.

Comment: Thank you. I know I can do it this way, however, I was wondering if I could do it in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

A common way to perform simple loops in R is to use `sapply()`. We can first identify programmatically the columns to be selected:

```
idx <- names(df) != "Date"
```

This logical vector will be used for the subsetting of the data.frame. One may further need to consider that the entries are probably stored as factors. In order to perform a multiplication they should be converted into numeric form, which is obtained by first coercing the entries into characters.

Therefore this should work:

```
df[idx] <- sapply(df[idx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))*0.0254)
#> df
#        Date      W1      W2      W3
#1 2014-12-18 11.5824 11.5824 11.5824
#2 2015-01-16 11.8872 11.8872 11.8872
#3 2015-01-30 20.0406 20.0406 20.0406
```

This subsetting and value assignment with `sapply()` is equivalent to a `for` loop like:

```
for (i in which(idx)) df[[i]] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[[i]])) * 0.0254
```

---

As pointed out by @akrun we could use `lapply()` instead of `sapply()` here. In this case the result would be the same. The description section of the help page `?lapply` summarizes the differences between these two functions:

> ‘sapply’ is a user-friendly version and wrapper of ‘lapply’ by
>        default returning a vector, matrix or, if ‘simplify = "array"’, an
>        array if appropriate, by applying ‘simplify2array()’.  ‘sapply(x,
>        f, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)’ is the same as ‘lapply(x,
>        f)’.